# Display different data while in different orientation in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, graph, orientation

What I wud like my app to ideally do is this, to show pivots with their contents in portrait mode and to show a graph when the phone is tilted and set to landscape mode.

I have used OnOrientationChanged() to detect the orientation changes.
Do i have to navigate to a new page if i have to show the graph? Or can i manage it in the same pivot page??

Again does windows phone have graphing tools? or have to rely on the 3rd party tools?

Alfah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just draw both controls and in OrientationChanged adjust the visibilities to what you need?  Remember to set your controls correctly for the initial state, too...

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Portrait)
    {
        MyPivot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MyGraph.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        MyPivot.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        MyGraph.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Collapsing does work but the pivot titles are visible only the the content gets collapsed. Is there anyway i can remove those too?

Comment: Wrap them all in a Grid / Canvas and set the visibility on the container control?